# mySQL Full Text search for words with specific first letter

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a very large database (10.000.000+) and I use full text search to work with it in a reasonable performance.

But there is one problem: In one case the user can search alphabetical by clicking on a letter. Yet I was working with LIKE 'C%' (e.g.) but this kind of search is very very slow.

Is there any possibillity to find all datasets by first letter of a field through MATCH/AGAINST?

Or can anybody tell me a much faster way but without MATCH/AGAINST?

With LIKE the search takes minutes to give reasonable response of data, this can't be the only way.

Answer (score 0):

If you search with `like 'C%'` in table with this amount of data it will definitly will be slow. Instead you can add `limit` to your query say first 50  with "Show More" link at the bottom of the search result and on click of link, again next 50 records will get displayed.  This approach might help you.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I could cut it down by country and other fields but I need a complete count of every found dataset to feed the pagination. Even if the result of the count is only 81 e.g. in one country on letter C it takes minutes to get the result...